# 18.04.2 use same files as W10?

Tags: file-sharing

I'm new to Linux and wondered where I can get useful info so started here. 1st off can I use the same PICTURES, VIDEOS, MUSIC & DOCS already on hard drive. I remember a window appearing during Linux installation saying it would require about 300gb for this, I clicked on OK but don't know how to get to them to appear. 
Since this my hard drive has gone down by 300 odd gb?